# ASP.NET MVC Highlight rows in table on link click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two views.  They each contain tables.  The first view has a table that has links in it that when clicked load the second view's tables.  I need to be able to highlight certain table rows in the second view's table when a link is clicked.  So if #@order.type = chargeback any row that is chargeback should be highlighted.  If @order.type = retroactive, then the retroactive rows should be highlighted.  The major problem here is that it has to happen on click in the first view.  I can't perform my logic in the 2nd view.  It has to be done in the 1st view, but I'm unsure how to access the data in the second view, in the first view.  Any ideas?

Here is my first view:

```
<style>
    .instant-hide{display:none;}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-center-block delayspiffdata">
            <table class="delay_spiff_tbl" id="table1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="blank"></th>
                        <th>Submitted Activations / Instant Spiff</th>
                        <th>Charge Back / $</th>
                        <th>Retroactive / $</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @for (int date = 0; date < Model.Count; date++)
                    {
                        <tr class="date-row" onclick="$('.date_@date').toggleClass('date-hide');">
                            <td class="spiffdate">
                                @Model[date].Date.ToString("dddd MM/dd/yyyy")
                                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle expander_open"></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>@Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.SubmittedActivationCount) / @Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.InstantSpiffTotal).ToString("C")</td>
                            <td>@(Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.ChargeBackCount) == 0 ? "--" : Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.ChargeBackCount) + " / " + @Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.ChargeBackTotal).ToString("C"))</td>
                            <td>@(Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.RetroactiveCount) == 0 ? "--" : Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.RetroactiveCount) + " / " + @Model[date].Carriers.Sum(c => c.RetroactiveTotal).ToString("C"))</td>
                        </tr>

                        for (int carrier = 0; carrier < Model[date].Carriers.Count; carrier++)
                        {
                            <tr class="date_@date date-hide" onclick="$('.submitted-@date-@carrier').toggleClass('carrier-hide');">
                                <td><span class="pull-left dash"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span> @Model[date].Carriers[carrier].Carrier</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="$('.carrier').not('.submitted-@date-@carrier').addClass('carrier-hide');$('.submitted-@date-@carrier').toggleClass('carrier-hide');pullDetails('@Model[date].Carriers[carrier].CarrierId', '@Model[date].Date', 'submitted-@date-@carrier', 'spiff')">
                                        @(Model[date].Carriers[carrier].SubmittedActivationCount == 0 ? "--" :
                                Model[date].Carriers[carrier].SubmittedActivationCount + " / " +
                                        Model[date].Carriers[carrier].InstantSpiffTotal.ToString("C"))
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="chargeback" onclick="$('.carrier:not()').not('.approved-@date-@carrier').addClass('carrier-hide');$('.approved-@date-@carrier').toggleClass('carrier-hide');pullDetails('@Model[date].Carriers[carrier].CarrierId', '@Model[date].Date','submitted-@date-@carrier', 'chargeback')">
                                        @(Model[date].Carriers[carrier].ChargeBackCount == 0 ? "--" :
                                Model[date].Carriers[carrier].ChargeBackCount + " / " +
                                        Model[date].Carriers[carrier].ChargeBackTotal.ToString("C"))
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="retroactive" onclick="$('.carrier').not('.ineligible-@date-@carrier').addClass('carrier-hide');$('.ineligible-@date-@carrier').toggleClass('carrier-hide');pullDetails('@Model[date].Carriers[carrier].CarrierId', '@Model[date].Date', 'submitted-@date-@carrier', 'retrospiff')">
                                        @(Model[date].Carriers[carrier].RetroactiveCount == 0 ? "--" :
                                Model[date].Carriers[carrier].RetroactiveCount + " / " +
                                        Model[date].Carriers[carrier].RetroactiveTotal.ToString("C"))
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="date_@date date-hide submitted-@date-@carrier carrier-hide carrier">
                                <td class="submitted_details" colspan="100%"></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.date-row').click(function () {
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('.date-hide').click(function () {
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
        });
    });

    function pullDetails(carrierId, startDate, divid, status) {


        $.get("@Url.Action("getInstantSpiffOrderDetails", "Dashboard")",
            { carrierId: carrierId, startDate: startDate, status:status},
            function (data) {
                $('.' + divid + ' .submitted_details').html(data);
                $('.' + divid).removeClass('carrier-hide');
            });
    }


</script>
```

Here is my second view:

```
<table class="delay_spiffgranular">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <th>Order No.</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Fill Date</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var order in Model)
        {
            <tr onclick="$('#instant_@order.OrderNo').toggleClass('instant-hide')" class="instant-row">
                <td>
                    @if(order.LinkedOrders.Count > 0){
                        <span class="pull-left dash"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (order.LinkedOrders.Count > 0)
                    {
                        @order.OrderNo
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a onclick="DisplayReceipt('@order.OrderNo')">@order.OrderNo</a>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>@order.Type</td>
                <td>@order.ProductName</td>
                <td>@order.Price.ToString("C")</td>
                <td>@(order.FillDate == null ? "--" : order.FillDate.Value.ToShortDateString())</td>
                <td>@(order.DueDate == null ? "--" : order.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString())</td>
                <td>@order.Username</td>
            </tr>
            if (order.LinkedOrders.Count != 0)
            {
                <tr id="instant_@order.OrderNo" class="instant-hide">
                    <td><span class="pull-left dash"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></span></td>
                    <td colspan="7">
                        <table id="instantTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Order No.</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Reason</th>
                                    <th>Fill Date</th>
                                    <th>Due Date</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var linkedOrder in order.LinkedOrders)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @if (@linkedOrder.Type == "Spiff")
                                            {
                                                <a onclick="DisplayReceipt('@linkedOrder.OrderNo')">@linkedOrder.OrderNo</a>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                @linkedOrder.OrderNo
                                            }

                                        </td>

                                        <td>@linkedOrder.Type</td>
                                        <td>@linkedOrder.Price.ToString("C")</td>
                                        <td>@linkedOrder.Reason</td>
                                        <td>@(linkedOrder.FillDate == null ? "--" : linkedOrder.FillDate.Value.ToShortDateString())</td>
                                        <td>@(linkedOrder.DueDate == null ? "--" : linkedOrder.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString())</td>

                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

UPDATED:

I put the following code in the 2nd view of my application.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('tr').each(function (index) { //iterate over all table rows
                if (index > 0) {     //skip header

                    if ($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim() != 'Prepaid Charge Back ') {
                        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
                    }
                    if ($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim() != 'Retroactive Prepaid Spiff') {
                        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all table rows, then find the ones that matches your condition.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tbody tr').each(function (index) { //iterate over all table rows
            if (index > 0) {     //skip header

                if ($(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim() != 'Prepaid Charge Back') {
                    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
                }
                if ($(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim() != 'Retroactive Prepaid Spiff') {
                    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Moe.  I apologize, I don't know JQuery.  Which view would I add this code to?  I'm not sure what should go under Do your logic here.  Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer, this should be placed in your second view, just add your css class

Comment: I added the script to my 2nd view and it still doesn't work.  I've updated my question with the script that I used.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe it's the third child. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.  in this line if ($(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim() != 'Prepaid Charge Back') { Wher it says != 'Prepaid Charge Back') This should be the text of the <td>

Comment: Would add a debugger above this line and see what's really inside the third TD?

Comment: I am not very good at debugging javascript.  I tried doing this console.log(('td:nth-child(3)').text()) but nothing is coming back in the browser.

Comment: umm.. put this to the console $(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').text()

Comment: it will only let me hover over $(this) it says the inner text for that is no item in cart.  I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: one of our senior developers came over and looked at it, and it looks like I'm going to have to rewrite it to make it work.  Thanks for your help.